# module.exports or this.func() { }?

Tags: node.js

In NodeJS, if we define functions using `this` keyword, it gets exposed.

for example:

```
// module.js

this.func1 = function () {
    console.log('func1');
}
```

Then, If you `require('module')` you can access func1.

I want to know that how it is different than `module.exports`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple test: create new file and do:

```
console.log( this );
console.log( module.exports );

this.test = 1;

console.log( this );
console.log( module.exports );
```

which clearly shows that `this` is a reference to `module.exports`, i.e. there is no difference.

Comment: I suggest using `module.exports`, because `this` keyword will change its meaning depending where you put it.

Comment: Right, but actually I want get a list of all the functions defined within the current module. So if I define them using `this`, then only  I am able to do that. is there any other way?

Comment: `module.exports.myFunc = function(){...}` If you can do this with `this` keyword, then you can obviously do this with `module.exports`. :)